# ngClass is skipping some classes and applying only one class on true

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ng-class

ngClass **is applying on only one class** from the **first three rows**, and will **apply all classes on the last row** :

```
  <ion-list id="wifiList-list2">
      <ion-item color="none" id="wifiList-list-item1" *ngFor="let wifi of wifi_list" on-click="goToSSID(wifi)">
       <!-- <ion-icon name="wifi" item-left></ion-icon> -->
        <div
          [ngClass]="{
            'signal-bars mt1 sizing-box good four-bars' : (wifi.level) < '0' && (wifi.level) > '-60',
            'signal-bars mt1 sizing-box four-bars bad one-bar' : (wifi.level) <= '-70' && (wifi.level) > '-90',
            'signal-bars mt1 sizing-box four-bars bad two-bars' : (wifi.level) <= '-67' && (wifi.level) > '-70',
            'signal-bars mt1 sizing-box four-bars ok three-bars' : (wifi.level) <= '-60' && (wifi.level) > '-67'
          }"
          >
          <div class="first-bar bar"></div>
          <div class="second-bar bar"></div>
          <div class="third-bar bar"></div>
          <div class="fourth-bar bar"></div>
        </div>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

In below screenshot any **wifi.level with value -35** will apply on **only one class "good" and skip the rest**. and any **wifi.level with value -63** **would apply on all the classes**: "signal-bars mt1 sizing-box four-bars ok three-bars"

[image]

Same as above screnshot, The **wifi.level = -73** is **applying only on the class "bad".**

[image]

When Removing `' '` and `( )` i the same results:

```
<ion-list id="wifiList-list2">
  <ion-item color="none" id="wifiList-list-item1" *ngFor="let wifi of wifi_list" on-click="goToSSID(wifi)">
   <!-- <ion-icon name="wifi" item-left></ion-icon> -->
    <div
      [ngClass]="{
        'signal-bars mt1 sizing-box good four-bars' : wifi.level < 0 && wifi.level > -60,
        'signal-bars mt1 sizing-box four-bars bad one-bar' : wifi.level <= -70 && wifi.level > -90,
        'signal-bars mt1 sizing-box four-bars bad two-bars' : wifi.level <= -67 && wifi.level > -70,
        'signal-bars mt1 sizing-box four-bars ok three-bars' : wifi.level <= -60 && wifi.level > -67
      }"
      >
      <div class="first-bar bar"></div>
      <div class="second-bar bar"></div>
      <div class="third-bar bar"></div>
      <div class="fourth-bar bar"></div>
    </div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: you mean It is skiping 'signal-bars mt1 sizing-box four-bars' and apending 'good' class only?

Comment: are you comparing numbers or strings, e.g. `(wifi.level) < '0'`?

Comment: @Chellappan yes its skipping the classes you mentioned

Comment: @ABOS numbers i guess, removing `''` and or `( )` get me to the same results.

Comment: @user1741397, what is wifi.level, a number?

Comment: @ABOS, `wifi.level` is a negative number eg. `-30` which represents the WIFI RSSI (ranges -90 to 0)

Comment: I have a feeling that changing numbers to positive numbers would solve this issue

Answer (score -1):

Compare the value of `wifi.level` with numbers without `''`.

Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: I get the same results when removing `''` from the numbers  (i tried earlier but got an error, but thats becouse i forgot to remove one `'`)

Comment: I also tried to remove `( )` from `wifi.level`  (and removed `' '` from numbers) but still getting the same results.

Comment: Can you update the code in the question with changes you made?

Comment: Replace conditions with this: `(wifi.level+90) < (0+90) && (wifi.level+90) < (60+90);`

Comment: Make changes in every condition of the `ngClass`. Let me know if it works!

Comment: I think you ment: `(wifi.level+90) < (0+90) && (wifi.level+90) > (-60+90),` which is smart but returns the same result :(

Comment: Maybe the negative numbers is not the issue, Note that whatever i put in the last line it will work so in this case the "ok" is always showing up correctly: `signal-bars mt1 sizing-box four-bars ok three-bars' : (wifi.level) <= '-60' && (wifi.level) > '-67'`

Comment: One of the classes mentioned there are going to load anyway. Here the problem is occurring while comparing the negative values. Can you check if solves the problem?

Comment: i added +90 as mentioned earlier and i got the same results

Comment: My apologies, Please have a look at the [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzyyrw](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzyyrw) , shows there is no problem in comparing negative values. So, please check if your `wifi.level` is an integer.

Comment: I think that `wifi.level` is an integer as value in json is not in quotes `" "`. I tried to add to your example parts of my code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2yyb4y   but for some reason it doesn't work but you can see my comments and json.

Comment: Also to note, they do seem to be calculated correctly as the red and thin or thicker green are showing in screenshots. Only problem is, its stripping some classes off - and always leaving `bad` or `good` classes. The last line would always show up correctly with all the classes (if wifi.level falls on whatever is on the last line).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188462/discussion-between-todarmal-and-user1741397).